# Cat6 run with junction box

Tags: networking

I’ve recently built an outbuilding in my garden and have run a cat6 cable to the house. Unfortunately the cable that was run wasn’t quite long enough so I’ve had to use a junction box to get it to the router.

So in the outbuilding I have a wall plate, connected to an external grade cat6 cable run through a conduit underground. When it reaches the house I’ve used a simple junction box to connect it to another cat6 cable which came with connectors. I connected one to the router and lopped the other one off and connected that end to the junction box.

I’ve connected them all in B format but I’m not getting any connection. Not sure if there’s anything I might be missing, have Re-cut them and connected them a couple of times, checked all the wires and it all looks good to me but can’t work out why it’s not working...

Comment: I cannot tell from the above, since you have re-terminated again.  Can you make a connection at the box with a laptop so that you can determine if the box or inside is an issue? That is how I would approach this.

Comment: I’ve connected a laptop at the wall plate but have no idea if the wall plate is working or if the junction box is the problem.  I’ve also realised that the connection from the router is a patch cable I tried to save myself crimping because I hate it but maybe I need to get exactly the same cable for the run indoor and just suck it up.

Comment: Does the junction box work when you connect a laptop? It seems no.  So (a) shed, cable   (b) junction box  (c) inside house.   I assume (c) works and until you know about (b) the shed (a) is not yet relevant.

Comment: I suppose the question is, is there anyway if testing my setup of the junction box? 

It’s one of these: https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/CXSM315.html or maybe there’s a better option for connecting them?

Comment: There are some on this page:  You may need a different box.  https://www.amazon.ca/SF-Cable-Junction-Punch-listed/dp/B0059DRCGI

Comment: What’s the difference between those just out of interest?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I think it is your box that is the issue. Seems so from here.

Comment: What kind of "junction box" did you use? Did you just connect two cables inside the junction box with each other? If so this is a bad setup. Prolonging Ethernet cables if you don't know exactly what you are doing will give you at the very least bad performance or as in your case simply won't work. Use a proper termination of the cable instead (plug and/or socket or better still get a cable with the right lengh, mind the max lengh within the different CAT specifications).

Comment: Try using a switch instead of a junction box.

Comment: Get a cheap cable tester and check what it shows. There are lots if variants, but even a cheap one will do - eg https://www.amazon.com/Optimal-Shop-Network-Tester-Ethernet/dp/B072LJYHKP

Comment: *"... and lopped the other one off"* -- Unnecessary if you had acquired an inline coupler (or keystone jack) instead of a junction box.   If you insist that *"it all looks good to me"*, then stop relying on visual inspection, and perform a basic continuity (electrical) test (on all eight wires) and also check for shorts.

Comment: Ive used an inline coupler like this: https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/CXSM315.html

Comment: Ah I didn’t know about a keystone jack, that would have been useful. To be honest I’m thinking of running a new cable the correct length, I just thought this might do the job but best to do it properly!